# Can a linked list have no data elements in it and still be a linked list?

Tags: list, linked-list

I read this while studying for interview questions:

"A linked list must have two things. It must have some data in each node, and it must have a reference to the next node. "

But can a linked list just have references to the next node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it will not be a linked list (by definition).

> a linked list is a data structure consisting of a group of nodes which together represent a sequence. Under the simplest form, **each node is composed of a data and a reference** (in other words, a link) to the next node in the sequence; more complex variants add additional links. This structure allows for efficient insertion or removal of elements from any position in the sequence.

[Linked list - wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list)

Answer (score 0):

I think that you just asked a bad question.

What would be the meaning of linked list , with nodes of empty information? You can implement it, but there is no meaning.

Comment: Yes, I know that it doesn't have any meaning, and it's not practical to implement it, but I nonetheless would like to know if it constitutes a linked list